# Split text into equal parts

Tags: bash, file, split

I have a phrase in one field in a file, which i need to break down into parts of 30 characters (including letters, numbers and spaces).

Ex.: "

```
This text is to show an example of what im looking for, to break the text into parts containing maximum 30 characters."
```

I need the following result:

```
This text is to show an exampl|e of what im looking for, to b|reak the text into parts conta|ining maximum 30 characters.
```

Could someone point me a direction?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for.  Do you want a single line of 30-character pieces separated by pipe (|) characters, as in your example? This is probably a job for `sed` and/or `awk`.

Comment: `sed 's/.\{30\}/&|/g' file` ?

Comment: Yes Lotharyx, would need a single line of 30-character pieces separated by pipe (|) characters, as in my example. Sed or awk are fine. Will try this code of yours and get back. Thanks

Comment: This sed comand worked perfectly! Do you want to post the answer with that code so i can give it as solved?

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `fold`

```
$ fold -w30 longline | tr '\n' '|' | sed 's/|$/\n/'
```

> This text is to show an exampl|e of what im looking for, to b|reak the text into parts conta|ining maximum 30 characters.

`sed` is to delete the last "|", note that '\n' substitution is not supported in all `sed`s.  If you have fever than 20 segments you can do the same with

```
$ fold -w30 longline | pr -20ts'|'
```

Also with the `-s` option you can set the breakpoints at spaces, might be better for human consumption

```
$ fold -w30 -s longline

This text is to show an
example of what im looking
for, to break the text into
parts containing maximum 30
characters.
```

vs

```
$ fold -w30 longline

This text is to show an exampl
e of what im looking for, to b
reak the text into parts conta
ining maximum 30 characters.
```

Comment: `fold` doesn't get enough good press. This is a good example of choosing the right tool for the job. The bash alternative of a c-style for loop incrementing 30 combined with string indexes is round-peg-in-a-square-hole solution by comparison (and not nearly as flexible)